# Does $\int^{\infty}_2 {e^{x/4} \over x^3({\ln x})^5} $ converge?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

> Does $$\int^{\infty}_2 {e^{x/4} \over x^3({\ln x})^5}dx $$ converge?

I don't know how to start - What can I compare it to? It seems too complicated.

How do you approach to this kind of problems?

Comment: Can you compare the asymptotic growth of the numerator and denominator?

Comment: The integrand doesn't even go to zero ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm I can see that.. but how do I prove something like that..?

Comment: Have you considered a comparison test?

Comment: @Stabilo: One of many possibilities would be to show that its logarithm goes towards infinity.

Comment: @zickens yes but I don't find what to compare with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have for all $n$:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^x}{x^n} = \infty$$

By applying L'hopital's rule $n$-times.

Also: $\log x \le x$ holds for all $x$.

Can you combine these facts to get something useful?